# logo pushing my main content despite it being in it's own tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give some padding to each side of my h1 logo but when i do it pushes my main content down. The h1 is inside a header tag so i don't see why it pushes it still. Right after the blue header there is only suppose to be 1px between the blue header and image.

```
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">New York</h1>
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Photos</li>
            <li>Videos</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ralphnyc/6n2qqruv/

Comment: where is your fiddle? its just a blank fiddle..

Comment: … and code is supposed to be *in the question itself* anyway. External sites shouldn't be essential to the understanding of a SO question.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6n2qqruv/2/) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n2qqruv/2/)

Add this to your CSS

```
header{
    float: left;
}
```

since your `<h1>` with class logo is floated left.

Comment: Did it help you @Ralphunreal ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` isn't containing the floated `h1` (the extra space you see is actually the padding around `h1` extending past the blue `header`). Add

```
header {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

To cause it to do so.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
header,
nav,
section,
footer {
  display: block;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #158ec5;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Britannic;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 26px 0 27px 34px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
.nycimg {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
footer {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h1 class="logo">New York</h1>

  <nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Photos</li>
      <li>Videos</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <img src="http://chichimiguel.com/storage/new-york-at-night.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1429898751997" alt="nyc picture" width="960px" class="nycimg">
    <article>
      <h1>PHOTOS</h1>
      <img src="">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h1>VIDEOS</h1>
      <img src="">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>&copy;2015 All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <a href="#">About Us</a> |
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
padding: 17px;
color: #fff;
font-family: Britannic;
font-size: 20px;
float: left;
font-size: 40px;
/* margin: 26px 0 27px 34px; */
```

Is padding what you want not margin